# Fixed line on top of zsh in terminal

Tags: plugins, terminal, window, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I'm trying to find if it's possible (and how to do it, if it is) to put a fixed line on top of the terminal using zsh. I would like to put into this line some system's information (for example cpu usage, disk free space, ram's usage, etc) preserving the classic "scrolling behaviour".

I would use it in windowed terminals in my desktop.

[image: Something like this]

Any idea/suggestion would be very apreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of trying to do this in `zsh` I would suggest using `tmux` for that. If you set the following in your `~/tmux.conf` it should have the desired effect:

```
set -g status-position top
set -g status-right '#(system-information-command)'
set -g status-intervall 10
```

It will put a status bar on top, print the first line of `system-information-command`'s output in it and update every 10 seconds.

#### Reasoning:

While it is quite easy to print something in the first line of a terminal from within `zsh` and - if wanted - updating it constantly is not that much harder, preserving scrolling behaviour will be very hard, if not impossible with just `zsh`.

The reason for that is that the scroll back buffer is maintained by the terminal and not by `zsh`. Any output to the terminal is done at the current position of the cursor. If anything is already printed at or after the cursor position, it will be overwritten. There is no way to insert anything.

Unless the cursor is explicitly set to a position it will be at the end of the last output, most of the time that is at the very bottom of the terminal. As said putting the cursor in the first line, writing something and resetting at to its previous position is quite easy. **But** anything that was in the first line before printing the status line will be overwritten. `zsh` can only write to the terminal, it cannot read from the previous output. So whatever the status bar overwrites it cannot be restored.

If you scroll up in the terminal the previously printed status line will move down together with the rest of the terminal's content. If the output of a command is higher than the terminal, at least one line will be overwritten.

`tmux` is a terminal multiplexer. It essentially runs a terminal (or more of them) inside your terminal. `zsh` and any program started in it would then run in the 'inner' terminal. Therewhile status line would be printed to the 'outer' terminal and not interfere with the shell's output.

Comment: I made it to work but using tmux I have 2 more problems:

1. I'm not able to scroll terminal anymore

2. When I clear my console the next line is written after more or less 6 lines from the top of the console

Answer (score 2):

You can abuse your prompt to display a fixed line at the top of the screen. It makes use of several ANSI escape codes for manipulating the position of the cursor.

- `\e[s` - save the cursor position
- `\e[u` - restore the cursor position
- `\e[H` - move the cursor to the top-left corner of the screen

Be sure to enclose any such escape sequences, as well as the text for the top line itself, in `%{ ... %}` so that `zsh` doesn't count them towards the size of your prompt.

```
PS1=$'%{\e[s\e[HTOPLINE\e[u%}%# '
```

Note that unlike `bash`, `zsh` does not treat `\e` specially in a prompt, so use `$'...'`-style quoting instead. If you can't (or don't want to) use them, you can try typing a literal escape character with <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>Esc</kbd> (which will show up as `^[`):

```
PS1='^[[s^[[HTOPLINE^[[u%# '
```

Comment: When I exported this PS1 in zsh it didn't recognize any of the ansi escape characters by default. Is there something else that you need to set so that they work?

Comment: My original post forgot to change the bash-style backslash escapes to zsh-style percent escapes, and it looks like I didn't do a good job of fixing that. I'll try to fix it later.

Comment: It has been a few years since this answer was posted. Is there a good way to have a fixed “header” or “status bar” in ZSH without abusing it too much since this was posted? Or is using TMUX like the other answer suggests, the best option?

Comment: At least in my opinion, this is a lot to do with a prompt, and it could be fragile in combination with other prompt components or command line tools. `tmux` also provides a *lot* of benefits aside from a persistent status bar, so I would recommend looking at `tmux` in any case.